# Issue with <select> tag on Android web browser

Tags: android, html, css, webkit, mobile-website

I have a problem with some Android devices. When I try to tap on some  tags it doesn't do anything. The weird thing is that I have some selects in another screens and they work great.
The only difference that they have is that the  tags who doesn't work have float:right; but I removed it and the bug still occurs. I don't know what could it be.

This is my markup:

```
<p class="dobholder">
    <select class="right" id="y" tabindex="31"><option>Year</option>...</select>
    <select class="right" id="d" tabindex="21"><option>Day</option>...</select>
    <select class="right" id="m" tabindex="11"><option>Month</option>...</select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `overflow: hidden` in your CSS on this element? Removing that fixed this issue for me